# Connecting to MySQL/sqlbuddy PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, connection

I'm having trouble getting my code to connect to my sql. I am creating in aptana with a wamp stack. When running, the web page only displays:

> cannot connect to DB: mysql_error(). " ); mysql_select_db ("q4u!") or
>   die ("cannot select db"); echo " Connected!
>
> "; $INSERT_sql = "insert into customer (cust_Fname, cust_Lname,
>   cust_Phone, cust_alt_phone, cust_Email, cust_notification_preference)
>   VALUES
>   ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[phonenumber]','$_POST[altphone]','$_POST[emailaddress]','$_POST[notipref]')";
>   mysql_query($INSERT_sql); ?>

my code looks like

```
    <?php 
    mysql_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "") or die ("<p>cannot connect to DB: mysql_error().</p>" );
    mysql_select_db ("q4u!") or die ("cannot select db");

    echo "<p>Connected!</p>";


    $INSERT_sql = "insert into customer (cust_Fname, cust_Lname, cust_Phone, cust_alt_phone, cust_Email, cust_notification_preference)
    VALUES ('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[phonenumber]','$_POST[altphone]','$_POST[emailaddress]','$_POST[notipref]')";


    mysql_query($INSERT_sql);  
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is not installed or the file extension is not .php

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$db = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306','root','');` do not include the `mysql_select_db` anymore.